# final keyword in method parameters not change

Tags: java, parameters, final

I have some questions about final. The code is as follows

```
public class Demo {
    private static Thread thread;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            fun("url-" + i);
        }
    }
    public static void fun(final String url) {
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(url);
                }
            });
        }
        thread.run();
    }
}
```

output:

```
url-0
url-0
url-0
url-0
```

why? I think it looks something like this

```
url-1
url-1
url-3
url-4
```

Comment: to start a thread, you should call the `.start()` method, also, you only make 1 instance of thread, and ignore the other calls because of the `if`

Comment: After the first call to `fun`, the `thread` class member is no longer `null`, you create the thread only once (with `url` being `url-0`), and you run the `run` method four times.

Comment: Also, you could replace the anonymous subclass of `Runnable` with just `() -> System.out.println(url)`.

Answer (score 1):

That keyword *final* on the parameter has nothing to do with what you observe.

What really happens here: you create **one** thread object, that is an instance of an anonymous inner **sub**class of Thread. And that instance gets url-0 as parameter. Then, afterwards, you call the `run()` method of that one Thread object 4 times. Thus the same object prints the same string 4 times.

To be more precise:

- the first time you enter `fun()`, the static `thread` field is null
- so a new instance is created, and the incoming string is *copied* into the context of that (subclass of Thread) object. That string is "url-0"
- then you call run() on that object 4 times

And as outlined in the comments: just calling `run()` on a thread object doesn't cause a real OS thread to do work in parallel. You have to call `start()` instead. But of course, it absolutely makes no sense to call `start()` **repeatedly** for the same thread.

So, in order for your code to do more of what you expect, try this:

```
public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        fun("url-" + i);
    }
  }
  public static void fun(String url) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(url);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `Thread` object once. It's this only instance that's being used with each subsequent invocations of your `fun` method. *This has nothing to do with the fact that `url` is `final`*

If you change your method implementation to something like this (making `thread` a local-scoped variable), you'll see that you get the expected output:

```
public static void fun(String url) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    });
    thread.run();
}
```

In other words, when you create your `Thread` object, it remembers the value of `url` that was passed to it. And because you are NOT creating other `Thread` objects when the `url` parameter takes a different value, you can only see the value of `url` that was passed when the object was created, which explains why you see `url-0` every time.

Comment: Or just `new Thread(() -> System.out.println(url)).run();` (however one should use `start()` instead of `run()`).

Comment: @MCEmperor 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the expected output because you are instantiating the `Thread` only **once** with the first argument **'url-0'**. Then, each time you call the method `fun`, you are just calling the method run on the only one created thread thread.run() with the argument 'url-0'